# The console in dev tools is blank

Tags: javascript, console, google-chrome-devtools

[image]I've been attempting to verify some information but I haven't been able to receive any data on the console. I suspect that my code may not be functioning properly, so I accessed just github.com/reddit.com, and here the console produced an error. Initially, I believed that this issue may be related to a problematic browser extension, so I disabled all extensions and opened an incognito window. However, in this case, the console is entirely empty. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what could be the issue?Below are the screenshots:

[image: Error one is of normal mode and blank is of incognito]

Tried running a js web app and found the console showing error. Then diabled the extensions and found the console completely blank.

Comment: The blank console is normal. What's exactly your question?

Comment: Not able to load anything in the console. How to fix the error shown in the below image?

Comment: The error in the image is related to browser extensions and should have nothing to do with your code. Disabling them and having the console remain empty confirms that, I believe. What are you developing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.